# How to visualize the double cover of $SO(4)$ as two copies of $S^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology, spin-geometry

> How to visualize the double cover of the rotational symmetry group of $S^3$ (which is $Spin(4)$, namely the double cover of $SO(4)$) as two copies of $S^3$?

This is due to $Spin(4) = SU(2) \times SU(2) = S^3 \times S^3$. But how to visualize the above  via the perspective of $S^3$?

Related question: [Implications of $\text{Spin}(3)\times \text{Spin}(3) \cong \text{Spin}(4)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4054495/141334)

Comment: You may enjoy Greg Egan's [SO(4) applet](https://www.gregegan.net/APPLETS/22/22.html)

Comment: It's debatable how much about this situation can be visualized. You can show all rotations are a product of a left and a right isoclinic rotation, and hence such pairs forms a double cover - which turns out to be Spin(4) - by making a simple observation about the parametrization $(\alpha+\beta,\alpha-\beta)$. You can argue any (strictly) left/right isoclinic rotation has a pair of invariant planes containing any given vector by arguing about $\Bbb R^4$ being made into a complex vector space, and then use that to see pairs of isoclinic rotations form an $S^3\times S^3$. This is mostly algebra.