# Isomorphism of the special orthogonal group

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

I want to determine whether $SO(4,\mathbb{C})=SL_2(\mathbb{C})\times SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ as Lie groups.

I have tried proving that they are not isomorphic by looking at simply connectedness. However, I am stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: We have
$$
SO(4, \Bbb C)=(SL(2, \Bbb C)×SL(2,\Bbb C))/\Bbb Z_2
$$
which follows the same way as the proofs in these posts

[How to visualize $SO(4) \simeq SO(3)\bigotimes SO(3) / \mathbb{Z}_2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600500/how-to-visualize-so4-simeq-so3-bigotimes-so3-mathbbz-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Why isn't $SO(3)\times SO(3)$ isomorphic to $SO(4)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46131/why-isn%27t-so3-times-so3-isomorphic-to-so4?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The Lie algebras however are isomorphic, and also
$$
\mathfrak{so}_4(\Bbb C)\cong \mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb C)\oplus \mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb C)\cong \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)\oplus \mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C).
$$

Comment: Hi. I suppose also that a short and sweet argument would be to count the number of elements in the center of each group