# Simple expressions of $\frac{SU(p) \times SU(p)}{\mathbb{Z}_p}$?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, intuition, group-isomorphism

We know that properties of $$\frac{SU(2) \times SU(2)}{\mathbb{Z}_2}={SO(4)}$$

1. Is there a nice group isomorphism of
   $$
   \frac{SU(p) \times SU(p)}{\mathbb{Z}_p}?
   $$
   for $p=3,4$?
2. If we include additional $U(1)$, do we have a nicer isomorphism to a familiar group?
   $$
   \frac{SU(p) \times SU(p) \times U(1)}{(\mathbb{Z}_p)^2}?
   $$
   for $p=2,3,4$?

All the mod factors are the centralizer subgroups.

Thank you <3.

Comment: Not that I know of. The first isomorphism is an example of what is called an exceptional isomorphism and these are rare; most compact Lie groups don’t have any exceptional isomorphisms.